Jpa and Hibernate could not determine recommended JdbcType for my Java type 'com.marketgb.productgb.Distribution'
I am having this error here below:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: 

Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'com.marketgb.productgb.Distribution'. 

And here below is what my Distribution Class looks like:
@Entity
@Table(name = "distribution")
public class Distribution {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Convert(converter = DistributionConverter.class)
    private Long distribution_id;

    @Column(name = "distribution_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String distributionName;

    @Column(name = "distribution_user_name", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String distributionUserName;

    @Embedded
    private DistributionOwner distributionOwner;

    @Embedded
    private DistributionContact distributionContact;

    @Embedded
    private DistributionLocation distributionLocation;



    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;
  
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "wholesale_id")
    private Wholesale wholesale;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "retail_id")
    private Retail retail;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer_id")
    private Buyer buyer;

I have added the relationship annotations like - @ManyToOne for the other Classes that relate with the Distribution Class. Yet the error still persists

Can you try implementing Serializable for you Entity ?

Please add the full stacktrace, please add all imports and package declaration to the classes. What do your other entities look like (generally you shouldn't have an @JoinColumn but a mappedBy attribute on the other side of the relation (unless that isn't there).

Hi @M.Deinum, thanks for your comment. I will check my codes for your instructions and see if it could be solved

Hi @antoine.lange, thanks for your comment. I will try your suggested approach.
